# how to give required response code in laravel?

Tags: laravel

friends I am new to laravel How to give required response code in laravel? for me, it returns 402 as a status code. please give the suggestion how to give a response code

```
  public function register(Request $request){
```

$this->validate($request, [
      'name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
      'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed'
        ]);



        $user = User::create([

        'name' => request('name'),
        'email' => request('email'),
        'password' => bcrypt(request('password'))
        ]);


     $params = [
       'grant_type' => 'password',
       'client_id' => $this->client->id,
       'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
       'username' => request('email'),
       'password' => request('password'),
       'scope' => '*'

     ];


     $request->request->add($params);
    $statusCode = 200;
     $proxy = Request::create('oauth/token','POST');
    $data = Request::dispatch($proxy);
    return response()->json($proxy, $statusCode);
     //return Route::dispatch($proxy);




      }</code><pre>

Comment: post you code please

Comment: What laravel version are u using?

Comment: laravel 5.5 version

Comment: i just started posting questions i can't able to post that code "it says your code not properly formatted." could you please tell me solution for that i am also searching

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are just returning the request where you generate your token, to return a response and be able to change the status code you need to put the result of your `Request::dispatch` call into a variable and then return a proper response with status code.

This is how you return a response with certain status code; how you are going to handle changing the status code is entirely up to you:

```
$statusCode = 200; //it can be any valid HTTP STATUS CODE
$data = Request::dispatch($proxy);
return response()->json($data , $statusCode);
```

Comment: can please tell me why  laravel  is giving 402 response code

Comment: **how you are gonna handle changing the status code is entirely up to you**

Comment: can you confirm again that with `return response()->json($data , $statusCode);` you get 402?

Comment: If you comment out `Request::dispatch($proxy);` and set `$data = [];` does it return 402 too?

Comment: thanks for your support i will research and let you know. i can't fix that its coming 402 as status code.